# What UI controls are used to make a properties list like the Xcode right hand properties panel?

Tags: macos, nstableview

I am trying to make a properties list similar to the Xcode properties list shown below. Ideally I want something like a NSTableView with static rows and static content for each row.

Any ideas on how to do this.  I can't see any obvious option in IB for NSTableView to set to using static content (similar to the option available in iOS UITableView) but the documentation indicates this is a property.  Currently I am trying to do this in IB but it's not really clear how to add additional static rows in IB.

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be in IB?

Comment: I guess not, can do it in code if required

Comment: Also, why does it have to be in a table view? Why not just a NSView?

Comment: Mainly because I like the  way the Xcode properties list works.  Looks like they are using and outlineView where you can collapse the sections and scroll etc.